# Detecting silence in Audio File (amr) using Java/Kotlin on Android Devices

Tags: java, android, audio, kotlin, android-audiorecord

Is there any library or method I use to achieve this? I know that I have to read the bytes in the files at blocks at a time, check if their values are below or above a specific threshold and detect the silence. However, I can't seem to find a library to **calculate rms or threshold values** of an audio file

Comment: Check this out it gets the gain from audio and other stuff https://github.com/google/ringdroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ringdroid/soundfile/SoundFile.java

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the RMS values manually. Check out the implementation by Samsung here: [android AudioRecord amplitude reading from MIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579184/android-audiorecord-amplitude-reading-from-mic)